# malformed line 59 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)

Tags: updates

I want to ask about the problem regard the problem which make me unable to install any updates:

malformed line 59 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)

This is my source code btw:

```
1   deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS _Trusty Tahr_ - Release amd64 (20150218.1)]/ trusty main restricted
 2  
 3  # See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
 4  # newer versions of the distribution.
 5  deb http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
 6  deb-src http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
 7  
 8  ## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
 9  ## distribution.
10  deb http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
11  deb-src http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
12  
13  ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
14  ## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
15  ## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
16  deb http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
17  deb-src http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
18  deb http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
19  deb-src http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
20  
21  ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
22  ## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
23  ## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
24  ## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
25  ## security team.
26  deb http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
27  deb-src http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
28  deb http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
29  deb-src http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
30  
31  ## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
32  ## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
33  ## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
34  ## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
35  ## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
36  deb http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
37  deb-src http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
38  
39  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
40  deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
41  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
42  deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
43  deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
44  deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
45  
46  ## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
47  ## 'partner' repository.
48  ## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
49  ## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
50  # deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
51  # deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
52  
53  ## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
54  ## developers who want to ship their latest software.
55  deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
56  deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
57  deb http://deb.playonlinux.com/ precise main
58  # deb-src http://deb.playonlinux.com/ precise main
59  deb http://deb.playonlinux.com/precise main
60  # deb-src http://deb.playonlinux.com/precise main
61  # deb-src http://deb.playonlinux.com/ precise main
```

Would really appreciate the help!

Comment: you have the list crashed between on the line `57  deb http://deb.playonlinux.com/ precise main` and `59  deb http://deb.playonlinux.com/precise main`, please choose one!!!

Comment: @abu-ahmedal-khatiri Sorry it really is my first time using linux, how can I choose one?

Comment: if you're choose the line of 57, disable the list on the line 59 with add `#`.

Comment: @abu-ahmedal-khatiriI I'm really confused right now, what's the terminal code for editting sources.list, there are many variations

Comment: use a Graphical Editor like `gedit` or `nano` with a path using `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` and find the line of 59 and add `#`. that should be `#deb http://deb.playonlinux.com/ precise main`

Comment: @abu-ahmedal-khatiri Thanks man! it workes!

Comment: if my answer section can helps you, accept it with green check!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned on comments section, you have the crashed on the list between on the line

```
57 deb http://deb.playonlinux.com/ precise main
```

and

```
59 deb http://deb.playonlinux.com/precise main
```

Edit your `sources.list` with a Graphical Editor like gedit or nano with a path using

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and find the line of 59 and add #. that should be

```
#deb http://deb.playonlinux.com/ precise main
```

Saved and update your apt.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I read it somewhere, do I need to replace 'precise' to 'trusty' to make it aligned with my OS?

Comment: if you will add a `Precise` Distribution into `Trusty` Distribution, i have tried! it will crash some package between `Precise` and `Trusty`. of course you don't need it!! change your `PlayOnLInux` Repository to Trusty Distribution like another the list on your `sources.list`.

Comment: if it's hopefully, try using a `UpVote` at my answer section with the mark of arrow up!!.

Answer (score 1):

```
57  deb http://deb.playonlinux.com/ precise main
59  deb http://deb.playonlinux.com/precise main
```

See the space before precise. Or you are missing the word "precise" before main.

Same goes for the commented line 60: missing space of missing the word "precise" before main.

It goes "deb" "url" "ubuntuversion" "main"

Comment: I read it somewhere, do I also need to replace precise with trusty to align it with my version?